# Can I sell my own house? Australia

Tags: real-estate, australia, selling

Are there any laws regarding this. I'm not an agent or anything but I have marketing and salesman experience. Will I be able to list my home privately on websites such as Realestate.com?

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward, though not "easy" (depending on your mindset). My father was an attorney. He got most of the conveyancing (house sales) done by his clerks... with just a quick review by a attorney.

Comment: @Albert - I've done it (Rosebud, Victoria). Easy. Best to work with an attorney that you know, who has experience in handling such matters. And make sure to put the yard signs in the ground the right way (not parallel to the road)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can sell your own house. There are various companies that can assist you with signage and advertising your own place.

Here are links to two websites that provide such a service:

[buyMyplace.com.au](https://www.buymyplace.com.au/)

[sellmyhouseonline.com.au](http://www.sellmyhouseonline.com.au/)

You can even advertise directly on [Domain.com.au](https://advertisers.com.au/domain) and do your own signage.

By the way you can do your own conveyancing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to list you property on Realestate.com directly, but there are "low service agents" who will list it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the oldest ones that still offers this service: https://www.forsalebyowner.com.au/

Some of the others don't seem to be around anymore.